# перевести объект в класс наследник python

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование

Допустим приходит человек на собеседование и мы добавляем его в базу:

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone_number = phone_number

man1 = People('Ivan', 'Ivanov', "+79998887766")
```

Нас человек устроил, он уже есть в базе и мы хотим присвоить ему новый статус "сотрудник":

```
    class Employers(People):
        def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, id, salary):
            super().__init__(first_name, last_name, phone_number)
            self.id = id
            self.salary = salary

man1 = People('Ivan', 'Ivanov', "+79998887766", 11, 100000)
```

Есть способ присвоения нового класса, при этом, все параметры что бы сами передались дальше в класс наследник, сократив при этом передаваемые параметры?

```
    class Employees(People):
        def __init__(self, id, salary):
            self.id = id
            self.salary = salary

man1 = man1(Employees(11, 100000)) #как-то так ?
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class People:
    
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        
        
class Employer(People):
    
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, id_, salary):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, phone_number)
        self.id = id_
        self.salary = salary
    
    @classmethod
    def from_people(cls, people_object, id_, salary):
        employer_obj = cls(
            people_object.first_name,
            people_object.last_name,
            people_object.phone_number,
            id_,
            salary,
        )
        return employer_obj

man1 = People('Ivan', 'Ivanov', "+79998887766")

man1 = Employer.from_people(man1, id_=11, salary=100000)
```

Comment: Неплохо, спасибо!) 
Правда не совсем понятно как работает "cls", и почему параметру "id" надо дописать "_"?

Comment: Аа, cls это как self, только хранит имя класса ?

Comment: Если точнее , то cls - это не только имя класса, это и есть сам класс. Через cls можно получить доступ ко всем атрибутам и методам класса.

Comment: К id я дописал _ только потому, что в питоне id - это уже занятое имя. Его, конечно, можно переопределить под свою переменную, и это будет работать. Но при этом в каких-то ситуациях это может привести к появлению "странных" и трудных для отладки проблем. Поэтому лучше не использовать под свои переменные системные имена. Можно либо дописать _, либо вообще изменить название переменной, например, на "employer_id".

Answer (score 0):

Я тут подумал, а что, если для класса People добавить метод:

```
def go_to_employees(self, id_, salary):
    self.__class__ = Employer
    self.id_ = id_
    self.salary = salary
```

Это будет полноценным объектом класса Employer?
И ещё, можно как-то получить список всех объектов класса, или единственный способ это создать локальную переменную класса, и при инициализации нового объекта её пополнять?

Comment: Если у вас появился вопрос, то его стоит задать как новый вопрос. Сама идея плохая, т.к. происходит нарушение абстракций.